# Can I conditional validate from parent struct value ? (https://github.com/go-playground/validator)

Tags: go

I'm trying to validate using https://github.com/go-playground/validator.

I'm facing problem that conditional validation depend on parent struct value.

First of all that validation can be done ?
If can not be, could you give me a hint that solve these problems.

Thanks.

```
type A struct {
  Enabled bool `json:"enabled" validate:"required"`
  Reason  struct {
        Note     string `json:"note" validate:"required_if=Enabled true"` // if parent's Enabled is true that struct will be required 
  } `json:"reason" validate:"required"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define `Reason` as pointer so it will be fine.

```
type A struct {
  Enabled bool `json:"enabled" validate:"required"`
  Reason  *Reason `json:"reason" validate:"required_if=Enabled true"`
}

type Reason struct {
        Note     string `json:"note" validate:"required"` 
}
```

Another way: u can custom the validate https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Custom_Validation_Functions